# Data type mismatch exception in Access query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access

I have the following code:

```
 public void GetParameterSelectionSet(int wire, int bond, string processProgramPath)
    {

        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + "data source=" + processProgramPath + ";";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * " +
                                                        "FROM BONDS INNER JOIN WIRES on " +
                                                        "BONDS.WireID = WIRES.WireID " +
                                                        "WHERE (WIRES.OperationOrder =  '@WireOrder') AND" +
                                                        "(BONDS.OperationOrder = '@BondOrder')", connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@WireOrder", OleDbType.Numeric));
                command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@BondOrder", OleDbType.Numeric));
                command.Parameters["@WireOrder"].Value = wire;
                command.Parameters["@BondOrder"].Value = bond;


                var mytemp = command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }

    }
```

When I execute this query i get a "Data Type mismatch in criteria expression".

Both WIRES.OperationOrder and BONDS.OperationOrder are of type Numeric. So I am lost as to why this is failing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WIRES.OperationOrder =  '@WireOrder' implies a string no?

Comment: And "@BondOrder" and "@WireOrder" are both ints? Are BONDS.WireID and WIRES.WireID of the same type?

Comment: I think the answer below by grahamj42 is right, but wanted to point out that you can shortcut your parameter creation and assignment like this: `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WireOrder", wire);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have put quotes around your numeric parameters in the SELECT statement, which is incorrect.

Comment: This was it. I need to to take the single quote marks off the numeric values. Thank you!